# Drastic slowdown using layer backed NSOpenGLView

Tags: cocoa, opengl, core-animation, layer

I needed to display some Cocoa widgets on top of an NSOpenGLView in an existing app.  I followed the example in Apple's `LayerBackedOpenGLView` example code.  The `NSOpenGLView` is given a backing layer using:

```
[glView setWantsLayer:YES]
```

Then the Cocoa `NSView` with the widgets is added as a subview of the `glView`. This is basically working and is twice ad fast as my previous approach where I added the `NSView` containing the widgets to a child window of the window containing the glView (this was the other solution I found on the web).

There were two problems.

- The first is that some textures that I use with blending were no longer getting the blend right.  After searching around a bit it looked like I might need to clear the alpha channel of the `OpenGLView`.  This bit of code that I call after drawing a frame seems to have fixed this problem:

Code:

```
glColorMask(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE); //This ensures that only alpha will be effected
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //alphaValue - Value to which you need to clear
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE); //Put color mask back to what it was.
```

Can someone explain why this is needed when using the `CALayer`, but not without?

- The second problem I don't have a solution for.  It seems that when I pan to the part of the scene where problem is #1 was observed, the frame rate drops from something like 110 FPS down to 10 FPS.  Again, this only started happening after I added the backing layer.  This doesn't always happen.  Sometimes the FPS stays high when panning over this part of the scene but that is rare.  I assume it must have something with how the textures here are blended, but I have no idea what.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a workaround to the slowdown.  The OpenGL view has a HUD (heads up display) view that goes on top of it.  I had installed another NSView as a subview if it.  Both the HUD and the subview have lots of alpha manipulation and for some reason that tickled a real slowdown in compositing the layers.  I could easily instal this subview as a subview of the OpenGL view and when I did this everything sped up again.  So although I don't fully understand the slowdown, I do have a good work around for it.