# Lag after adding a NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController to NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

The following code was recently added to an existing application.  buttonHolderView is a NSView with a NSButton control inside.

```
if ((NSInteger)NSAppKitVersionNumber >= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10) {
    NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController *pinButtonViewController = [[NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController alloc] init];
    pinButtonViewController.view = self.buttonHolderView;
    pinButtonViewController.layoutAttribute = NSLayoutAttributeRight;
    [self.window addTitlebarAccessoryViewController:pinButtonViewController];
}
```

The application presents one or more windows to the user, each having a NSOpenGLView playing a video feed.  As the number of these windows increases, a lag in responsiveness increases on OS X 10.10.  It appears the main thread is being taxed a great deal more.

Instrument time profiler data comparisons between runs with the new code and without showed the percentage of time spent inside [NSApplication sendEvent:] is less than 1/2 (3.4% down to 1.4%) what it usually is without the accessory view in the title bar which is expected with the lag experienced.  There is also a notable increase in the time spent within [NSView displayIfNeeded] (26% increasing to 39%).

Any thoughts on how to correct this lag is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Download Graphic tools for Xcode [Graphic tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=graphic)

Try to debug from there with flash screen updates

There is also something about poor performance of layer backed views on 10.10 (bug) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464133/poor-performance-using-layer-backed-nsopenglview)

[image: Debug Menu]